# snap to run when not logged in

Tags: cron, snap, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I am trying to create an IOT using a Raspberry Pi3 with Ubuntu Core.

I have written my snaps (they do file operations) and I can executed them just fine when I am logged in.

However all processes seem to be killed once I close the ssh session and thus the snaps are no longer executed.

To prove this I packed the following *.sh in a snap and stated it.

```
while true; do
   echo "runnning: "$(date) > test.status
   sleep 5m
done
```

This works as long as i am logged in. If I close the ssh session and open a new one the process is no longer running.

Also checked with `ps -a`

Does any one know how to keep processes (snaps or shell scripts) active on Ubuntu Core when I log out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what the app is actually doing, but it sounds like you really want it to be a service, no? You can do that with a slight tweak to the YAML, for example:

```
    apps:
        my-app:
            command: my-binary
            daemon: simple
```

Now my-app will be a systemd unit, starting on boot.